# Factoring in Efficiency in Equations

Tags: mathematics, water-resources

A pretty simple question, but one that's weirdly confusing me:

I'm working with an equation for total water demand (Q) were w is the allowance for water wasted. w is typically 30%. Most books therefore present the equation (I'm simplifying it here by replacing the bits irrelevant to my question with x) to...

$$ Q=x(1+w) $$

The first equation makes sense to me. One book (also by a recognized authority on the subject) however factors in the loss in efficiency this way: 
$$ Q=\frac{x}{1-w} $$

Could someone help me reconcile the two?

Comment: Did you double check that all the variables are defined in the same away and that the units are the same between both the equations?

Comment: So provide the sources and detail of how each book explains the formulae then the difference may be found.